# How do I eliminate the margin from textview with empty string?

Tags: android, layout, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

So, I have a relative layout that looks like this:

```
ImageView TextView1
TextView2
```

Suppose, the content of TextView1 is "" (empty string), and all the views and layouts are set to wrap_content, the ImageView, then is supposed be in the center of the relative layout, right? But, it seems that the right margin is always greater than the left margin. I doubt this is caused by TextView1. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code so we can help you better.

You can try use the View.GONE when your string is empty.

```
TextView TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
String text;
TextView1.setText(text);
if(text == null)
   TextView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the visibility `View.GONE` for `textview1` when it's empty and apply the layout param ["alignWithParentIfMissing"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignWithParentIfMissing) on ImageView1 to make it occupy the whole parent (if you align `ImageView1` on the left of `TextView1`).